# Calculation of an indefinite integral containing $\sin(x)$ and $x$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have to calculate this simple integral:
$$J(x)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{\sin(t)-t}dt$$ 
Despite its apparent simplicity, I can't figure it.
Is there some method to calculate it? Thanks.

Comment: The integrand has a non-integrable singularity in $0$, $\sin t - t = - \frac16t^3 + O(t^5)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : what does it mean ti say non integrable singularity? Does it mean its value does not exist at $t=0$ or is there something more to look... please explain

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik It means more, the limit $\lim\limits_{\delta\to 0} \int_\delta^x \frac{dt}{\sin t-t}$ does not exist (or is not finite, if you allow infinite limits), compare my answer.

Comment: Is it at all possible that you were assigned an exercise that said "Find the derivative of the following functions", and this was one of them? It's actually a commonplace mistake for students to think that they've been asked to find the integral when they see one like this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: it's a kind of integral appearing in the solution of $\dot x(t)+x(t)=\sin(x(t))$

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra In that case, if $x(t)$ has a zero, it is identically zero, and your integral has to stay away from $0$ (it would require infinite time to reach $0$ from any nonzero position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small positive $t$ (say $0 < t < 1)$, we have $- \frac16 t^3 < \sin t - t < -\frac16 t^3 + \frac{1}{120}t^5 < - \frac{19}{120} t^3$. Thus for $0 < \delta < \varepsilon < 1$, we have

$$-6\int_\delta^\varepsilon \frac{dt}{t^3} > \int_\delta^\varepsilon \frac{dt}{\sin t - t} > - \frac{120}{19} \int_\delta^\varepsilon \frac{dt}{t^3}.$$

Since $\lim\limits_{\delta \searrow 0} \int_\delta^\varepsilon \frac{dt}{t^3} = +\infty$, we have a non-integrable singularity in $0$. If we want to interpret

$$J(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sin t-t}$$

at all, we must interpret it as $J(x) = -\infty$ for $x > 0$ (and $J(x) = +\infty$ for $x < 0$).

Comment: I doubt that this is not the way to do! but i can not say it strongly as i do not know how to do this properly.. :(

Comment: The (non-inline) displayed relations need to be turned to $>$.

Comment: Oops, thanks, @ccorn.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: For $0<t<1$, the terms of the power series for $\sin t$ alternate in sign and take strictly decreasing absolute values. This justifies the estimates shown.